# Javascript get all combinations of given segments that combined fit perfectly in a given size

Tags: javascript, math

I have a size that I want to see if it can be divided in any combination of certain sections. For example I want to see if 96 can be composed of sections of 18, 21 and 24 size (it should give [24,24,24,24] and [18,18,18,21,21]). The problem is that the function should receive any size with any number and sizes of sections. And I am stuck.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should figure out without any thought of JavaScript; like, think about how you'd do it with pencil and paper.

Comment: decompose your number to a multiplication (what is the right word here?) of prime numbers

Comment: My problem is I am stuck and for some reason can't find a suitable solution for some hours now. It would've been somewhat easy with a fixed number of sections, but this function must allow any size, any number of sections.

Comment: @evgenifotia: I don't see how that helps: 91 is 17*2+19*3, both 17 and 19 are prime numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a brute force approach and add a value as long as the left over value is positive.

```js
function getParts(sum, sizes) {
    function iter(left, right, index = 0) {
        if (left < 0 || index === sizes.length) return;
        if (!left) {
            result.push(right);
            return;
        }
        iter(left - sizes[index], [...right, sizes[index]], index);
        iter(left, right, index + 1);
    }

    const result = [];
    iter(sum, []);
    return result;
}

getParts(96, [18, 21, 24]).forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I will have to understand it too :)